# How to get random generated Numbers with no Repeat

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop, random, flashdevelop

Hey everyone I have seen some forums about this but can't seem to figure it out still.

So I have an Array called `aClockArray` and this is a custom array which has 4 Movie clips inside of it. The nested Movie clips have a different color for each frame. I have the array set up like so in my constructor:

```
aClockArray = [playScreen.wire_5, playScreen.wire_6, playScreen.wire_7, playScreen.wire_8];
```

Then in another Function I have a for loop setup to iterate through all objects in array and have them gotoAndStop on a random Frame in their Nested Movie clip it goes from 2-7 that I have it randomize like so:

```
private function randomColorGenerator():void 
    {
        //Loop through wires and make them randomn generate color
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aClockArray.length; i++)
        {
           var currentWires = aClockArray[i];

           nWire = randomNumber(2, 7);

           currentWires.gotoAndStop(nWire);


        }
    }
```

Now this works perfect and I get random colors every time I restart. But What I would like to accomplish is for the colors not to repeat so not to have the `nWire = randomNumber(2, 7);` 2-7 numbers repeat. How would I go about doing this to have these numbers random generate and not repeat?

Also Here is my `randomNumber` function:

```
//Generates a truly "random" number
    function randomNumber(low:Number=0, high:Number=1):Number
    {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
    }
```

Thank you any help would be appreciated!

Tried something like this but still has duplicates :(

```
//Loop through wires and make them randomn generate color
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aClockArray.length; i++)
        {
           var currentWires = aClockArray[i];
           var frames:Array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
           var randomFrame:uint = frames.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * frames.length), 1);


           currentWires.gotoAndStop(randomFrame);


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of the unique possible results:

```
var frames:Array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

Then remove from that array at a random index with [`splice`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29):

```
var randomFrame:uint = frames.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * frames.length), 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for this Ill let you know how it goes when I try it out later today!

Comment: It may be *slightly* faster to randomize the array first, then use `pop()` or `shift()` (what @Flashist is *trying* to accomplish), but this is also a good solution and the most compact.    Unless your are running the code every frame, there should not be any performance difference.

Comment: Still confused about how I would implement this. Will I still be using my current for Loop? Adding something like this to it and splicing it from there?

Comment: I tried something like  currentWires.gotoAndStop(randomFrame); but it only produced all of the same color

Comment: Updated my answer with what I tried if you could take a look thanks its on the bottom of the question

Comment: @Nathan almost! At the moment you recreate the array in every iteration. The line that declares the array should be outside the for loop (but still inside the function)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like:

1. Create predefined list of values
2. Randomize the list
3. Shift the first value of the list during each iteration

For example:

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    function randomizeSort(obj1:Boolean, obj2:Object):int
    {
        var randNum:int = -1 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
        return randNum;
    }

    var framesList:Vector.<int> = Vector.<int>([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    framesList.sort(randomizeSort);
    trace(framesList);

    var tempColor:int;
    var clipsList:Vector.<MovieClip> = Vector.<MovieClip>([playScreen.wire_5, playScreen.wire_6, playScreen.wire_7, playScreen.wire_8]);
    var clipsCount:int = clipsList.length;
    for (var clipIndex:int = 0; clipIndex < clipsCount; clipIndex++)
    {
        tempColor = framesList.shift();
        trace(tempColor);
    }
```

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis it's not the constructor, but the [top level function Vector.<T>](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Vector%28%29) Another shorthand `Vector` notation is [`new <int>[1, 2, 3]`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee5.html#WSB1F41227-C612-4f33-A00E-CE84C1913E1C)

Comment: @null - I stand corrected.   Guess I need to use shorthand more often.  Not that I've even done an AS3 project in the better part of a year.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal candidate for prototyping:

```
MovieClip.prototype.gotoRandomFrame = function():void
{
    if(!this.frameReferences)
    {
        this.frameReferences = [];
        for(var i:int = 0; i < this.totalFrames; i++)
        {
            this.frameReferences.push(i + 1);
        }       
    }
    var index:int = this.frameReferences.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.frameReferences.length), 1);
    if(!this.frameReferences.length)
    {
        this.frameReferences = null;        
    }
    this.gotoAndStop(index);
}
```

Thx to this prototype you can now call this method on any mocieclip and have them display a unique frame of their timeline until they have displayed them all and they start over.

```
mymovie.gotoRandomFrame();
```

The other answers are correct but they don't account for the multiple movieclip situation. It would be bad to have to create as many pieces of code and arrays as you have movieclips.

Comment: If you edit the prototype, you're creating one array per instance (whether you need the functionality or not). Far better to create a Class definition and either extend it into some other Class or just set it as the Class for the MovieClip symbol.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I don't like to use prototype either, but to be fair, the `frameReferences` array only gets attached if you call the `gotoRandomFrame()` method.

Comment: Still a bit confusing on how to implement this. Still going at it with no luck. Tried Nulls method but no luck

Comment: Cannot disagree more Amy, First you are not correct, movies that don't need the functionality don't create any additional array. Second it's an ideal candidate for prototype instead of Class because it removes the need to implement it specifically for each movie that needs it which is a time saver. Nathan just put that code anywhere inn your project (at the start is better) and any movie will be able to call that method.

Comment: don't get me wrong guys, I'm not advocating for the use of prototype which I rarely use myself but there are some cases where this kick trick is right on the spot and can save a ton of time, I think this is that case here.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not going to give you the exact code, since I don't write in actionscript.  But, you just need to save the last color you used and avoid it:

```
{next_color = randomNumber(2,7)} until next_color != last_color;
currentWires.gotoAndStop(next_color);
last_color = next_color;
```

Viola!  Pseudo random colors.

Comment: Interesting Thank you for the advice I will definitely try it out today!

Comment: Will that ensure that the first and third number are different?

Comment: The questioner only asked for pseudorandom numbers that did not repeat.  (i.e. don't play the same video two times in a row)  He did not specify that the result should not match any previous entry.  If you read more into the question, that's not my fault.